# jQuery API not working on iPhone 3G

Tags: javascript, jquery, encryption

I have a javaScript that encrypts the data from the mobile browser using jQuery.jCryption.encrypt(). The above code works on almost all mobile phone browser but when i use this on iPhone3G with 4.2.1 OS, the encryption doesn't seem to happen. On the server side a flag is being sent to check if the java-script is enabled. The flag is being set since the browser supports java-script which is causing an issue since server is trying to decrypt data which is not encrypted.

Is there any way to check if the jQuery is supported by the browser? And is there any alternate to the above design?

Comment: Have you tried enabling the mobile web console in iPhone 3G? See if it says something... It has helped me a ton of times when developing for the iPhone (especially the 3GS)

Comment: Turning on the web console was useful. There was an error in the java-script when CiUI was used for iPhone. The script had to be modified to remove the error. Thanks.